# -bash: ./ideal.exe: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using the windows subsystem of Linux to run the 2D hill test model from the WRF test cases.

I am in the test case directory and the first step is to run "./ideal.exe". However, I get the following message:

```
-bash: ./ideal.exe: No such file or directory
```

Using ls I can see that the file is present in the directory:

```
README.namelist  ideal.exe  input_sounding  namelist.input  wrf.exe
```

I tried:

```
ls -ld ideal.exe
```

Once again it cannot find the file

Comment: Show the output of `ls -ld ./ideal.exe`. Please [edit] your question to answer.

Comment: Does the `.exe` have the executable bit set? `ls -ld ./ideal.exe` should show something starting with `-rwx`. If not try `chmod o+x ideal.exe` or however Windows makes files executable.

Comment: I am not sure if ideal.exe has an executable bit set, I'll try chmod .

Comment: @Robert There's a different error if permissions are wrong.

Comment: There's probably a character in the filename that you can't see. Use `ls -b` to show non-printing characters as escape sequences.